# How to get into Xilinx ZCU102 u-boot prompt

Tags: linux, xilinx, u-boot

I am trying to run a simple hello_world program in u-boot command prompt. I have followed this https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/147882060/Executing+application+from+u-boot+on+ZCU102 to get the application running on the u-boot, however, I am not able to exit from my application(system hangs after executing the application). I want to get back to u-boot prompt. How can I achieve this?

My program looks like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    print("Hello World\n\r");
    return 0;
}
```

I loaded the Hello_world.bin using fatload from the SD card, and executed the binary using go command.

```
IWG35M> fatload mmc 1 0x6000000 Hello_World.bin
36936 bytes read in 15 ms (2.3 MiB/s)
IWG35M> go 0x6000000
## Starting application at 0x06000000 ...
Hello World
```

Now How do I exit from this application and get back to u-boot prompt? Any suggestion would be gratefully received.

########### Update ##############

Steps for creating the Hello_World.bin

1. Install Vitis 2020.2.(In our case Vitis is installed on `/opt/Xilinx/` path).
2. To configure the environment to run the Vitis software platform, run the following scripts, which
   set up the environment to run in a specific command shell:
   For example in our case `source /opt/Xilinx/Vitis/2020.1/settings64.sh`
3. Launch the Vitis IDE by executing the `vitis` command.
4. Create platform project.
   File -> New -> Platform project -> Create from hardware specification(XSA) -> Browse(Select zcu102.xsa) -> keep everything default(as attached screen shot below) -> Finish.

[image]

5. Right click on the platform project -> build project.
6. Create application project.
   File -> New -> Application project -> Select the platform project created in the above steps -> Keep everything default -> Select Hello World template -> finish.
7. Right click on application project and build project.

From here follow the below wiki https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/147882060/Executing+application+from+u-boot+on+ZCU102.

Comment: I deleted my orginal answer, since I had missed the fact that you were able to execute `add.bin`, and that only the second attempt was failing because the program had returned after having be switched to `EL1`. I was ultimately able to download.use Vitis, and to disassemble the hello_world program. This second version should correcly answer to your original question. More specifically, it does explain why your program does never return to the u-boot command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I achieve this?

That is possible, but start with the sample code at **examples/standalone/hello_world.c**.
If U-Boot is configured properly, then this "standalone" program is automatically built with an ordinary **make** command.

From U-Boot's **README** file:

```
U-Boot supports the following image types:

"Standalone Programs" are directly runnable in the environment
provided by U-Boot; it is expected that (if they behave
well) you can continue to work in U-Boot after return from
the Standalone Program.

...

Standalone HOWTO:
=================

One of the features of U-Boot is that you can dynamically load and
run "standalone" applications, which can use some resources of
U-Boot like console I/O functions or interrupt services.
...
```

The salient requirements are that you use U-Boot's **make** file and CONFIG_STANDALONE_LOAD_ADDR is properly defined (e.g. the start of main memory).
Use of U-Boot's API is recommended, especially if you want to return back to U-Boot's command prompt.  This will cause your "program" to use U-Boot's already allocated stack and heap.

When your program allocates its own stack (as your tested code does), it is discarding the return address to the calling U-Boot code.  Hence your code is stranded, and cannot resume U-Boot.

> Now How do I exit from this application and get back to u-boot prompt?

An ordinary return statement from the main procedure will resume execution at the U-Boot prompt (assuming your program conforms to the API and does not clobber the stack or the U-Boot image in high memory).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, `u-boot` is *primarily* meant to replace itself with a whole other kernel, there's generally no way to exit back to the `u-boot` prompt.

Having said that, it's possible you *could* get back after your program runs by rebooting the device rather than trying to exit from it. The device will then come back up in its normal boot state (the `u-boot` prompt). Just keep in mind this will only work if you don't auto-boot into another kernel.

*How* you reboot depends, of course, on your environment. For example, the software on our iMX6 boards go through a series of increasing violent attempts sixty seconds apart until they succeed (`reboot`, `systemctl reboot`, `systemctl --force reboot`, `systemctl --force --force reboot` then an unstoppable GPIO sequence that will reboot even the *most* recalcitrant boards).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right to think that this can be achieved by using the `go` u-boot command when using a standard version of u-boot: it actually is more like a `call` command than a `go` command, and  it will display the return code returned by the program.

example #1 - `el.c`

```
#include <stdint.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    register uint64_t __regCurrentEL;
    __asm volatile ("mrs %0, CurrentEL" : "=r" (__regCurrentEL));
    return __regCurrentEL >> 2;
}

CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-
${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc -O0 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -e main -Wl,-Ttext=0x0000000042000000 -o el.elf el.c
${CROSS_COMPILE}objdump -D el.elf > el.lst
${CROSS_COMPILE}objcopy  el.elf -O srec el.srec
```

using the resulting el.srec:

```
=> loads
## Ready for S-Record download ...

## First Load Addr = 0x42000000
## Last  Load Addr = 0x42000023
## Total Size      = 0x00000024 = 36 Bytes
## Start Addr      = 0x42000000    => go 0x42000000

## Starting application at 0x42000000 ...
## Application terminated, rc = 0x2
=>
```

The result is the expected one, since u-boot is usually running at `EL2` on a `aarch64` system.

I could of course have loaded the the program using

```
fatload mmc 1 0x42000000 el.bin
```

You program shall avoid corrupting the `u-boot` environment and shall comply with the [Procedure Call Standard for the Arm Architecture](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0042/latest/) when being called from u-boot.

I personally prefer this approach to the u-boot Standalone one because there are no dependencies whatsoever to the `u-boot` source code and its build procedure.

An interesting feature is that whatever extra arguments will be passed to the `go`command will be accessible from int `main(int argc, char** argv)` using argc and argv.

example #1 - `add.c`

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rc = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        rc += *argv[i] - '0';
    }

    return rc;
}

CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-
${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc -O0 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -e main -Wl,-Ttext=0x0000000042000000 -o add.elf add.c
${CROSS_COMPILE}objdump -D add.elf > adl.lst
${CROSS_COMPILE}objcopy  add.elf -O srec add.srec
```

u-boot:

```
loads
## Ready for S-Record download ...

## First Load Addr = 0x42000000
## Last  Load Addr = 0x4200006B
## Total Size      = 0x0000006C = 108 Bytes
## Start Addr      = 0x42000000
=> go 0x42000000
## Starting application at 0x42000000 ...
## Application terminated, rc = 0x0
=> go 0x42000000  1
## Starting application at 0x42000000 ...
## Application terminated, rc = 0x1
=> go 0x42000000  1 3 5
## Starting application at 0x42000000 ...
## Application terminated, rc = 0x9
=>
```

You may have, and I would advise you, to use the `dcache flush`/`icache flush`  commands in the case you would successively load/execute two different programs from the same address: some bizarre things may otherwise happen.

This having been said, Xilinx did not do anything to allow you to use this feature, that is allowing you to execute a program and return to the u-boot prompt. This is likely that this was never one of their requirements:

a) They diverged from the standard implementation of the `go` command so that it would start the program at `EL1`, from say, the `EL2`or `EL3` u-boot is running at, using `armv8_switch_to_el1()`: that means that, once you have executed, say, `add.bin` once, you will return to u-boot at `EL1`, and `u-boot` will never allow you to use the `go` command again. This is why you first attempt was working, and your second one failed:

First attempt:

```
fatload mmc 1 0x6000000 add.bin
108 bytes read in 9 ms (11.7 KiB/s)
$ go 0x6000000
## Starting application at 0x06000000...
## Application terminated, rc = 0x0
```

Second attempt:

```
go 0x6000000 1
## Starting application at 0x06000000 ...
FAIL: current EL is not above EL1
## Application terminated, rc = 0x16
```

The code for the Xilinx version of `go` is explicit:

```
unsigned long do_go_exec(ulong (*entry)(int, char * const []), int argc,
             char *const argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;

    if (current_el() > 1) {
        smp_kick_all_cpus();
        dcache_disable();
        armv8_switch_to_el1(0x0, 0, 0, 0, (unsigned long)entry,
                    ES_TO_AARCH64);
    } else {
        printf("FAIL: current EL is not above EL1\n");
        ret = EINVAL;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The conclusion of this first part is that yes, you can execute programs and return to the u-boot command prompt. You may from there use u-boot commands for examining the memory to see if your program worked as expected, or use other commands.

But if you want to use `go` again, you will have to restart u-boot.
From there, if you wanted to use `go` the way you can on, say, an Allwinner platform, you could modify back the implementation so that u-boot will not switch to `EL1` prior to execute the program, and install the modified version on your system:

```
unsigned long do_go_exec(ulong (*entry)(int, char * const []), int argc,
             char *const argv[])
{
    int ret = 0;

    if (current_el() > 1) {
        smp_kick_all_cpus();
        dcache_disable();
        ret = entry(argc, argv);
    } else {
        printf("FAIL: current EL is not above or equal to EL1\n");
        ret = EINVAL;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

An alternative would be to add a new `go2` command that would use the implementation above.

b) The startup code for the hello_world programs does not preserve the registers according to the ARM calling conventions, and even more, it does clear all the registers as suggested in some ARM application notes:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_vector_table>:
       0:   1400024e    b   938 <_boot>
    ...
     200:   14000061    b   384 <SynchronousInterruptHandler>
    ...
     280:   14000082    b   488 <IRQInterruptHandler>
    ...
     300:   140000a1    b   584 <FIQInterruptHandler>
    ...
     380:   14000099    b   5e4 <SErrorInterruptHandler>


0000000000000938 <_boot>:
     938:   d2800000    mov x0, #0x0                    // #0
     93c:   d2800001    mov x1, #0x0                    // #0
     940:   d2800002    mov x2, #0x0                    // #0
     944:   d2800003    mov x3, #0x0                    // #0
     948:   d2800004    mov x4, #0x0                    // #0
     94c:   d2800005    mov x5, #0x0                    // #0
     950:   d2800006    mov x6, #0x0                    // #0
     954:   d2800007    mov x7, #0x0                    // #0
     958:   d2800008    mov x8, #0x0                    // #0
     95c:   d2800009    mov x9, #0x0                    // #0
     960:   d280000a    mov x10, #0x0                       // #0
     964:   d280000b    mov x11, #0x0                       // #0
     968:   d280000c    mov x12, #0x0                       // #0
     96c:   d280000d    mov x13, #0x0                       // #0
     970:   d280000e    mov x14, #0x0                       // #0
     974:   d280000f    mov x15, #0x0                       // #0
     978:   d2800010    mov x16, #0x0                       // #0
     97c:   d2800011    mov x17, #0x0                       // #0
     980:   d2800012    mov x18, #0x0                       // #0
     984:   d2800013    mov x19, #0x0                       // #0
     988:   d2800014    mov x20, #0x0                       // #0
     98c:   d2800015    mov x21, #0x0                       // #0
     990:   d2800016    mov x22, #0x0                       // #0
     994:   d2800017    mov x23, #0x0                       // #0
     998:   d2800018    mov x24, #0x0                       // #0
     99c:   d2800019    mov x25, #0x0                       // #0
     9a0:   d280001a    mov x26, #0x0                       // #0
     9a4:   d280001b    mov x27, #0x0                       // #0
     9a8:   d280001c    mov x28, #0x0                       // #0
     9ac:   d280001d    mov x29, #0x0                       // #0
     9b0:   d280001e    mov x30, #0x0                       // #0
```

This of course does make gracefully returning to u-boot impossible, even though this is a good approach if you don't have to return to the callee.

c) The program executed by u-boot should return to the calling code, but the startup code for the demo program does in fact enter an endless loop, which is usually fine, but not in your use-case:

```
00000000000014c0 <_exit>:
    14c0:   14000000    b   14c0 <_exit>
```

Working around the current behaviour would require to modify the startup code provided by Vitis, or to use your own modified version of it, so that:

- the registers used by u-boot would be saved/restored,
- the program would return instead of entering an endless loop.

Of course, you should modify the behaviour of the `go`command as explained above, so that the program would not be executed at `EL1`: This is perfect for security and production systems, but really bad for learning. I am personally using a u-boot running at `EL3` while learning about the `Armv8-a` architecture.

This will require way more work/testing, and may or may not be worth it depending on what exactly you are planning to do.

Comment: @Prasanna Kotrappa Does this answer your original question, or does it need to be improved? thanks.